# systemd-networkd DenyList= does not work

Tags: linux, networking, systemd

My current `systemd` version is

```
# systemd --version
systemd 249 (249.11-0ubuntu3.4)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP -LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY -P11KIT -QRENCODE +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified
```

I'm trying to user the `DHCP`'s `DenyList=` ([man](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html)):

> DenyList=
> A whitespace-separated list of IPv4 addresses. Each address can optionally take a prefix length after "/". DHCP offers from servers in the list are rejected. Note that if AllowList= is configured then DenyList= is ignored.

It does not work.
`systemd-networkd` says, in debug mode: `... DHCP 'DenyList=' IP address is invalid, ignoring assignment: 1.1.0.0/16`.

And I do get an IP address `1.1.2.100` from my `DHCP` server.

This is my network file:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/network/50_mgmt_enp4s0.network 
[Match]
Name = enp4s0

[Network]
DHCP = ipv4

[Link]
# mtu
MTUBytes = 1500

[DHCP]

[DHCPv4]
DenyList = 1.1.0.0/16
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`can optionally take a prefix length` was added in systemd version 250. You're running v249, but the online manual is for the latest version available (currently v254).

Comment: Thank you.
I also tried to set in the `DenyList=` the exact IP I was given from `DHCP`, but it didn't work either. But, no error was issued that time.
Did I still get this IP because some kind of cache?

Comment: The option accepts a list of DHCP _server_ IP addresses, not a list of issued addresses. Networkd should mention the server's IP address in its regular logs (it's likely to be the same as the gateway's address).

Comment: ok, now I'm confused.
I thought it says to the DHCP server that this client wouldn't accept these addresses as an IP address. "DHCP offers from servers in the list are rejected".
Thank you.